# Automatically redirect to child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router in my AngularJS app and I have routes like this:

```
angular.module('app.messages').config(function($stateProvider, ACCESSLEVELS) {
    $stateProvider.state('messages', {
        url: '/messages',
        templateUrl: 'messages/list.html',
        controller: 'MessagesListCtrl as controller',
        resolve: {
            'conversations': function(Restangular) {
                return Restangular.all('conversations').getList();
            }
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('messages.detail', {
        url: '/{conversationId:[0-9]{1,8}}',
        templateUrl: 'messages/conversation.html',
        controller: 'MessagesDetailCtrl as controller',
        resolve: {
            'conversation': function(conversations, $stateParams) {
                return conversations.get($stateParams.conversationId);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

So if you go to `/messages` it'll show a list of your conversations (and it contains a `ui-view` for the details view). If you go go `/messages/1` you view a single conversation.

When you go to `/messages` you should automatically be redirected to the most recent conversation, because just showing the list and a message like "Select a conversation from the list" is just stupid :)

The problem is that I don't know how to do this. If I have some redirect logic in the MessagesListCtrl then you'll always have a delay where you see the empty landing page and are then redirected. I can't do it a resolve function since those are also used by the child state. Surely others have had this same problem, how did they solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `messages` an abstract state, keep the `resolve`, and move the `templateUrl` and `controller` to a new state, `messages.list`. Then, create a parent `<ui-view />` for your `messages` state, and give it a `templateUrl` with whatever you want the user to see while the message is loading. *Should* work.

Comment: It might be easier in combination with ui-routers upcoming optional parameters? If there is no $stateParams.conversationId then use the last one from the conversations array.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the help of Nate's answer above:

```
angular.module('app.messages').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('messages', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'messages/list.html',
        controller: 'MessagesListCtrl as controller',
        resolve: {
            'conversations': function(Restangular) {
                return Restangular.all('conversations').getList();
            }
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('messages.list', {
        url: '/messages',
        templateUrl: 'messages/conversation.html',
        controller: 'MessagesDetailCtrl as controller',
        resolve: {
            'conversation': function(conversations) {
                var lastId = _.last(_.sortBy(conversations, 'lastwrite')).id;
                conversations.selectedId = lastId;

                return conversations.get(lastId);
            }
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('messages.detail', {
        url: '/messages/{conversationId:[0-9]{1,8}}',
        templateUrl: 'messages/conversation.html',
        controller: 'MessagesDetailCtrl as controller',
        resolve: {
            'conversation': function(conversations) {
                conversations.selectedId = $stateParams.conversationId;

                return conversations.get($stateParams.conversationId);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Basically messages.list and messages.detail show the exact same template and use the same controller. The resolve is just a bit different. I'm keeping track of the selectedId on conversations so I can mark the active conversation in the list.